# I am trying to hash admin password to save into database using bcrypt in nextjs but receiving error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, next.js, bcrypt

so everything is fine if I do not import bcrypt but once I do it I receive the following error in the terminal. I have searched a lot with no luck at this point I am clueless as what to do. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
error - ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/clean.js:8:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js
./pages/adminlogin.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

here is my adminlogin.js file

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
export default function AdminLogin() {
  const saltRounds = 10;
  const createAdminData = async (e) => {
    const usernameInfo = e.target.username.value;
    console.log(usernameInfo);
    const passwordInfo = e.target.password.value;
    const salt = bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds);
    const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(passwordInfo, salt);
    const res = await fetch("api/database/addadmindata", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: usernameInfo,
        password: hashedPassword,
      }),
    });
    const result = await res.json();
    router.reload();
  };
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and running `npm install` again? Also, as a side note: bcrypt's `hash` is async, so you should await it if you are not providing a callback to the method as a third parameter.

Comment: @ivanatias yes tried that did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error happens because in client-side somewhere in your app you are using `fs` module. you can use `fs` module only on the server side, either `getserverSideProps` or apis directory.

When you import "fs" and use it in server-side, next.js will see that you use it in server-side so it won't add that import into the client bundle

probably that @mapbox is not a client library but you are using it in client-side

You probably have mongoose userSchema. in that schema file:

```
// hashing password before saving user
// for findAndUpdate(), pre save hook is not triggered
userSchema.pre("save", async function (next) {
  // if password did not get changed, next()
  if (!this.isModified("password")) {
    next();
  }
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
});
```

Now you do not need to do hashing on the server. you extract the data from `req.body`, you contract the `user` with the raw password, then run

await user.save()

so before "user" is saved, raw password will be hashed automatically and hashed password will be saved to the database

Comment: so can I use it in my api so that it hashes the receiving password before it saves  the database?

Comment: @Kamran probably that `@mapbox` is not a client library but you are using it in client-side. what is the npm link of that package

Comment: I believe it was bundled with bcrypt package

Comment: the only package I installed was bcrypt so it is the only explanation

Comment: if it is so, u have to use the bcrypt on ly in server side. where is `adminlogin.js` is executed

Comment: sorry if it sounds kinda basic,I am pretty new . could I send the credentials to server then hash it on the server then aadd the hashed password to database? is it a viable solution?

Comment: @Kamran that is the correct way of doing it. I will post the easiest way of doing it

Comment: @Kamran I dont know why I assumed that you had a monggose schema. do you have or otherwise I will delete the example

Comment: i do have mongoose schema

Comment: great. I showed the example how to do handle the password hashing easy way

Comment: so this example code runs on server?

Comment: yes. Because you will be using mongoose models on the server, in api functions

Answer (score 1):

You can use "bcryptjs" instead of "bcrypt", it works fine in client-side of nextjs 13

Comment: The question in not asking how to use bcrypt in client side. Your answer is not relevant and can be a "comment"